# Rewrite $\ln(z)-\ln(x)-\ln(y)$ in compact form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am to rewrite $\ln(z)-\ln(x)-\ln(y)$ in compact form. The solution in my textbook says it's $\ln(\frac{z}{xy})$.

I'm confused by this since  thought that a product, as seen in the solutions denominator, only happens when there's a summation of logs?

My attempted answer:

$$\ln\left(\frac{z}{\frac{x}{y}}\right).$$

Why is my answer incorrect and why does the solution contain a product of logs when there's only subtraction in the original question?

Comment: $$-(\ln(x)+\ln(y))=-\ln(xy)$$

Comment: Hint: $\log z - \log x - \log y = \log z - (\log x + \log y) = \log z - \log (xy)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it helps seeing that:
$$\ln(z)-\ln(x)-\ln(y) = \ln(z) - \Big(\ln(x)+\ln(y)\Big).$$

At the same time, I think you're thinking of it as:
$$
\Big(\ln(z)-\ln(x)\Big) - \ln(y).
$$
Even in this case, the term inside the $\ln(\cdot)$ function amounts to:
$$
\frac{z}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{y} = \frac{z}{xy}.
$$

Comment: or more literally, $\frac{z/x}{y}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln z-\ln x =\ln \frac zx$$

$$\ln \frac zx-\ln y=\ln \frac z{xy}$$

Note that $\ln x - \ln y=\ln \frac xy$, but does not equal $-\ln x - \ln y$.